# css position fixed inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some content that I want the text fade effect at the bottom. In order to do that I have to use `position: fixed;` inside a `div` with `overflow-y:scroll`

The div that gives the fade effect does not appear. I have tried different solutions but none have worked inside a div.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/b2jz1yvr/1417/) example of the code

Comment: you should look at `absolute`, not `fixed` since that is relative to the viewport. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: yes, tried that but when scrolling text the <div class="fadeout"></div> also scrolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using `absolute` positioning. Something like:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2jz1yvr/1419/)

```
.outer {
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.fadeout {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(95%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
}
```

Note that I put `overflow: scroll` on `.content` instead of `.outer` to keep the blur from scrolling.

Using `fixed` positing will place the blur at the bottom of the user's viewport, rather than the element.

Comment: now replace the `.fadeout` by a `:after` on the `.outer` and you are right on the money: http://jsfiddle.net/b2jz1yvr/1420/

Comment: That's a nice solution as well. I like to answer using the user's original structure (as long as its valid) to help them understand why their code wasn't working originally.

Comment: validity can be discussed here imo. The fadeout is clearly styling and has no semantic purpose. Therefore it should be part of the css, and not the markup. But I get your point...